# Fluent API - Configuring multiple instances of the same class within an entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two classes below, `Form` and `FormFieldOption<T>`. The latter is intended to represent a set of `<option>` inside of a `<select>` in a web form that the `Form` object represents.

```
public class Form
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public FormFieldOption<string> Status { get; set; }
  public FormFieldOption<string> Category { get; set; }
  public FormFieldOption<int> Severity { get; set; }
}
public class FormFieldOption<T>
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public bool Active { get; set; }
  public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

I'm working on configuring these entities for Code-First like below:

```
public class FormFieldOptionStringConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<FormFieldOption<string>>
{
  public FormConfiguration()
  {
    //configure here
  }
}
```

Unfortunately at this point I've discovered that I would like there to be a difference between the configuration for the `Status` and `Category` properties. I've not been able to figure out a way top configure the properties that utilize the `FormFieldOption` class individually. How could I do this?

Solutions I've come up with:

- Create a new class that inherets `FormFieldOption<T>` for each property and configure individually.
- Create an interface `IFormFieldOption<T>` and implement classes individually for each use.

I don't particularly care for either of these options as it feels like a lot of duplicated code just to create a different configuration for each table.

Comment: What version are you using? But I am not sure you have other options in any version of EF.

Comment: I'm using EF 6.2.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that you can't do this. What I ended up doing was creating a generic interface that I implemented for each property.